# Postman accessing the stored results in the database leveldb

Tags: postman

So I have a set of results in Postman from a runner on a collection using some data file for iterations - I have the stored data from the runner in the Postman app on `Linux`, but I want to know how I can get hold of the data. There seems to be a database hidden away in the `~/.config` directory `(/Desktop/file__0.indexeddb.leveldb)` - that looks like it has the data from the results there.

Is there anyway that I can get hold of the raw data - I want to be able to save the results from the database and not faff around with running newman or hacking a server to post the results and then save, I already have 20000 results in a collection. I want to be able to get the `responseData` from each post and save it to a file - I will not execute the posts again, I need to just work out a way

I've tried KeyLord, `FastNoSQL` (this crashes), `levelDBViewer`(Jar), but not having any luck here.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

inline 25024 of runner.js a simple yet hack for small numbers of results I can do the following

```
RunnerResultsRequestListItem = __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2_pure_render_decorator___default()(_class = class RunnerResultsRequestListItem extends __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_react__["Component"] {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    var text = props.request.response.body,
      blob = new Blob([text], { type: 'text/plain' }),
      anchor = document.createElement('a');
    anchor.download = props.request.ref + ".txt"; 
    anchor.href = (window.webkitURL || window.URL).createObjectURL(blob);
    anchor.dataset.downloadurl = ['text/plain', anchor.download, anchor.href].join(':');
    anchor.click();
```

it allows me to save but obviously I have to click save for now, anyone know how to automate the saving part - please add something here!

Comment: obviously I can post the data to a server instead of the manual clicks....